# Работа на удаленном компьютере или распределение нагрузки.

Tags: windows, ssh

Есть планшет с док-станцией Acer W501 на win7, домашний компьютер и MS VS. Подскажите как наиболее выгодно (в плане быстродействия) подключаться к домашней машине удаленно, какие программы использовать и тд. А также слышал об распределении нагрузки, будто на одной машине управлялось, а на удаленной компилировалось или выполнялась другая ресурсоемкая работа. Насколько второй подход реален и какой подход эффективнее. Полезные ссылки приветствуются. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее быстродейственно будет использование RDP протокола - можно воспользоваться родной утилитой под windows "удалённый рабочий стол". Распределённая нагрузка в вашем случае возможна (насколько мне известно) в двух случаях. Первый - это создание вычислительного кластера, Второй - настройка конкретной программы, если у неё есть такая функция, как например 3d studio max